# Passing arguments to higher order functions

Tags: scala

how do I pass different parameters for my function inside a higher order function. my code below.

```scala
val sum = (a: Int, b:Int) => a + b
    
val x = 7
val y = 9
    
def sq (x: Int, y: Int, f: (Int, Int)=> Int): Int = {
  x + y * f(a,b)
}
    
println(sq(x,y,sum(2,3)))
```

This doesn't work and throws an error that `'a' is not defined`.

Comment: What is the point of passing a **Function** if the **method** receiving it doesn't know how to call it and rather is the user the one to call it? Like why not just asking for: `def sq (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Int = x + y +z`?

Comment: `a` and `b` are the names to be used inside the function `sum`. You are going to pass values `x`, `y` as `a`, `b`; hence `x` and `y` will take place of `a` and `b` in function call. so your `sq` will be `x + y * f(x, y)` (if you want square then `(x + y) * f(x, y)`) and you will call `sq` as `sq(x, y, sum)`. Actually you don't even need to define those `val x =  7` and `val y = 9`. You can directly use `sq(7, 9, sum)`.

Comment: Can you define with words what `sq` should do? How it should use `f`?

Comment: Also note that you are mixing `x` and `y` as method parameter names and as variables defined outside the method, this is confusing to understand what you really want to do

Answer (score 2):

The parameter list for sq looks ok.
The call to sq isn’t right, the function would get evaluated before it gets passed in. Assuming it got by the compiler, which of course it doesn’t.

Passing in a function does not mean its arguments come along for the ride. Passing in a function means the caller may not know what arguments to use or even if the function should be called.  The sq function has to supply arguments when it calls it. a and b mean nothing outside the definition of sum. sq could supply x and y as arguments to sum.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to @Nathan answer. This example would make sense:

```
val sum = (a: Int, b:Int) => a + b
   
    
def sq (x: Int, y: Int, f: (Int, Int)=> Int): Int = {
  x + y * f(x, y)
}

val x = 7
val y = 9
    
println(sq(x,y,sum))
```

This would be evaluated in your `sg`function like:
`7 + 9 * sum(7, 8)`

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `@Nathan Hughes` answer, if you want to pass the different argument to the sum function on each call you need to change your `sq` method like

```
def sq (x: Int, y: Int, f: (Int, Int)=> Int): (Int, Int)=> Int = {
  x + y * f(_: Int, _:Int)
}
```

Insted of expecting the int from the `sq` method return partially applied function of type `(Int, Int) => Int` from `sq' then pass other argument to that function like,

```
sq(10, 20, sum)(1, 2) // 1st approach

//2nd approach would be
//You can hold the function in another variable and call that function with other arguments
val partialSum = sq(10,20, sum)
partialSum(1, 2)
```

and you will get your result.

Or if you still want that `sq` method should return `Int`, you can define your `sq` method like

```
def sq (x: Int, y: Int, f: (Int, Int)=> Int)(a:Int, b:Int):Int = {
   x + y * f(a, b)
}

scala> sq(10,20, sum)(1,2)
res2: Int = 70
```